# Filemaker self join portal filtering

Tags: filter, duplicates, filemaker, portal, self-join

I have a database of items that are imported from a number of XML sources, into a table called **Import**.

Each XML source has its own **SourceID** number. This number is put in every item record.

Each import is logged in a related table called **Import_History**. This logs the SourceID, date of each import, and how many items were imported.

So...

**TABLE: IMPORT**

SourceID = Number

**TABLE: IMPORT_HISTORY**

fk_SourceID = Number

ImportDate = Timestamp

ImportCount = Number

**RELATIONSHIP**

Import::SourceID = Import_History::fk_SourceID

**WHAT I NEED**

On the **Import** table layout, I want a portal that shows records from **Import_History** so I can see when each XML source was last imported. I only want to show the **most recent** Import_History record for each SourceID.

I think I need a cartesian join between Import and a new table occurence of Import_History (**Import_History_All**), and a self join of a new table occurence of Import_History (**Import_History_All_Self_Join**).

So...

**Cartesian**

Import::SourceID x Import_History_All::fk_SourceID

**Self Join**

Import_History_All::fk_SourceID = Import_History_All_Self_Join::fk_SourceID

**WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR**

I have followed this:

http://www.filemakertoday.com/com/archive/index.php?t-32667.html

and this:

http://scarpettagroup.com/filemaker-portal-show-distinct-value-tutorial/

But it does not filter the records. I always get all of the Import_History records in the portal. I have endlessly googled and not figured this out.

Can anyone help?

---

```
**EXAMPLE DATA**

*Import*

 - SourceID: 1234
 - Item: Widget1
 - Price: 3

 - SourceID: 1234
 - Item: Widget2
 - Price: 5

 - SourceID: 1234
 - Item: Widget3
 - Price: 10

*Import_History*

 - fk_SourceID: 1234
 - ImportDate: 22/03/2016 12:00:00
 - ImportCount: 3

 - fk_SourceID: 1234
 - ImportDate: 21/03/2016 12:00:00
 - ImportCount: 2
```

Comment: This is a strange arrangement, where SourceID is not unique in either table. It seems to me that records in the Import table are related to records in the Import_History that have nothing to do with them in reality. I am not sure what this is supposed to accomplish - perhaps you need to revise your plan.

Comment: I tried to keep things simple for clarity. The SourceID relates to another table, which I'll call **Sources**. This is joined to **Import** in order to supply LookUps with information.

Comment: Ok, so why don't you use this table instead?

Comment: Because users spend almost all their time in the Import layout and I'd rather have a quick button they can press to give them a quick list of the most recent date for each source's Import.

Comment: I meant why don't you show a portal to this table instead?

Comment: Because that table doesn't hold the dated list of imports. It is a table for information about each XML source.

Comment: We are going in a circle. That table can get the latest import date using a sorted relationship. That's the shortest (and fastest) path to what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Import_History_All::fk_SourceID = Import_History_All_Self_Join::fk_SourceID

The relationship above is a join that will result in every record with the specified source ID being displayed in the portal. Basically the relationship above will display the designated portal records in the IMPORT HISTORY table that have the same SourceID. If you wanted to view the most recent record for the sourceID of the record you are on this would be the relationship that is required, and all that would be left is sorting the portal and filtering to only show the most recent value. This would be fine, if you wanted only the most recent importation for the SourceID you are currently on.

> On the Import table layout, I want a portal that shows records from Import_History so I can see when each XML source was last imported. I only want to show the most recent Import_History record for each SourceID.

The most efficient way to display only the most recent record of each SourceID would be to utilize another table to store the most recent values. This table would contain records with unique values for Source ID ( each source has only one record ) that would contain the Import ID of the most recent record. The import ID is a primary key for the Import_History table that you would add to define a distinction between each Import_History record. Modification of your current importation script is necessary to achieve this result. The modifications should include a variable that captures the Import_ID. The relationship between the tables **Import** and **Import_Tracking** will only bring up one record, and then you can use the **set field** script step to set the field Import_Tracking::Most_Recent to the previously defined variable that holds the value of Import_ID. At this point you have the **Import_Tracking** table, which contains the unique Import_ID of the most recently updated record for each source. You can use a Cartesian join in the **Import** table with the **Import_Tracking** table to show all the records in the **Import_Tracking** table, which only has the most recent importID for each unique source. If you want to see data from the **Import_History** table all that you need to do is create a relationship between the **Import_Tracking** and **Import_History** table, and then you can place related fields inside of your portal to view the data. I have included the relationships and fields that should be added below. Please let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

**RELATIONSHIP:**

Import::SourceID = Import_Tracking::fk_SourceID (w/ ability to add records via relationship)

Import_Tracking::Most_Recent = Import_History::ImportID

**TABLE: IMPORT_HISTORY**

fk_SourceID = Number

ImportDate = Timestamp

ImportCount = Number

ImportID = Text/Number (Primary Key)

**TABLE: IMPORT_TRACKING**

fk_SourceID = Number

Most_Recent = Text/Number (Whatever you defined "ImportID" as)

Answer (score 0):

> I want a portal that shows records from Import_History so I can see
>   when each XML source was last imported. I only want to show the most
>   recent Import_History record for each SourceID.

If you sort the related records from Import_History by ImportDate (in the relationship setup), then the most recent import will become the *first* related record.

If you place fields from Import_History directly onto a layout of  the Import table (outside of any portal), they will show data from the first related record in Import_History.

This presumes one simple relationship where:

```
Import::SourceID = Import_History_All::fk_SourceID
```

I don't see why you would need any other.

Comment: Hi - I have a layout for the Import table. Somewhere on that, I want to be able to see a full list of the various SourceIDs and the latest ImportDate for each. At present the portal is in a convenient popover button. This facility will tell the users at a glance what is the oldest import so they can do them in order. i.e. import the XML feed that is oldest.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Say I'm viewing the **Import** layout, and looking at a record that has a SourceID of 1234. Your suggested related **ImportDate** and **ImportCount** fields will show '22/03/2016 12:00:00' and '3' respectively. But to see the latest dates of every distinct SourceID means navigating to lots of records that have the correct SourceID. They won't be in a list that is easily understood.

Comment: I would suggest you use a third table where SourceID would be unique. You can populate such table on-demand, or as part of the import routine. This table could be related to the history table as described above - or it could store the latest import's date too. The way you are going about it now is too convoluted (and slow) IMHO.

Comment: Note: to filter a portal to show only unique values only, see: http://fmforums.com/topic/71906-getting-more-out-of-filtered-portals-3unique-values/

Comment: As far as I can see, the self join relationship is a tried and tested method for the problem I am trying to solve - I just can't get it to work.

Comment: The self-join relationship is a tried and tested method to filter a *relationship* - as opposed to filtering a *portal*. Before portal filtering became available in version 11, filtering a relationship was the only way to remove duplicates. It's still preferred when the number of related records is large. For filtering a portal, the additional relationships are not required - as shown in the demo I have linked to.

Comment: I will in the future have many more Import_History records - there are around 100 sources, each of which may be imported daily. How many is 'large'? I will check out that link you kindly gave me.